# SQL query to get count of records in Table A and also in Table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables name `Table 1` and `Table 2`. Both of these table contain a column named `address`. `Table 1` contains about 1200 records while `Table 2` has another 1 million records on store.

Now, what I'd like to do is to find the count of records in `Table 1` where a row with a matching address also exists in `Table 2`.

I am new to SQL - could anybody please tell me how to get the aforementioned row count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select Count( * ) from Table1
Where address in ( select address from Table2 )`

Comment: I would still recommend a join in this case. That is what they are for and generally are much faster then sub-selects.

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*) from Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.address = Table2.address
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a JOIN. Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.address = table1.address;
```

Note:
if this is a frequent query you should put an index on the address field in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COIUNT(*) FRO Table1 WHERE address IN(SELECT address from table2)
```